# How to copy F-Curve Modifier(s) from one object to multiple objects in Blender 2.8x

Tags: python, modifiers, fcurves

I have an object that animates to float up and then starts slowly rocking in mid-air.

I achieved this by using the Noise modifier for the different location/rotation values and it looks good, my only challenge now is somehow copying all those different modifiers to 30 different individual objects but as far as I'm aware Blender doesn't support this functionality natively, so I looked online and came across this [old post](https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/blender/A/question/17866.html) but I'm not sure entirely what I'm doing and if it even applies to 2.8x

If anyone could help me execute this efficiently I'll be so thankful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're still wondering about this, here is a way that can speed things up hopefully.

Copy the modifier, select all the other objects and filter to show the curves you want to paste to, then select all the curves and hit paste. Now make sure the "Only Active" option is deselected and you're done.

[image: Select curve you want to copy modifier from]

[image: Copy modifier]

[image: Select all, paste and make sure "Only active" is deselected]