# how to extend this animation to infinity?

Tags: animation, graph-editor, nla-editor

So I have this kind of animation:

[image: screenshot of F-curve showing step function]

It changes the location of an object in steps:

```
on frame 24, it is 0
on frame 25 it becomes 4
on frame 49 it 4
on frame 50 it becomes 8
```

unfortunately my knowledge in nla/using cycles modifier or any other modifiers in graph editor is very limited.

So my question is: how can I extend that animation without manually copying the keyframes and moving them?

*** UPDATE ***

Although I answered my own question here if would still give the "right" check to somebody who can also present me a solution for solving this without a driver; and shows me a way with nla/graph editor because I am sure I need this for more complex animations where I don't have an easy formula, but a repeating steps of an animation which just "adds" it values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the *Stepped Interpolation* f-Curve modifier is the one you're looking for?

[image]

.. although you have to do the arithmetic a bit backwards, from your POV ..(start-value, end-value, frame-length of step).

Or.. if you want the cycle to go on for ever, this might be your way..

[image]

Set one step as keyframes, with <kbd>T</kbd> > 'Constant' interpolation, and then  set  a *Cycles* modifier as shown above.

> Note: As Gordon mentioned it is important to check which channel is selected. If you don't select explicitly one channel Blender will take the "default" channel which is x, if you don't select another one.

Comment: @Chris .. oops, missed the way which is closer to your OP.. see edit.

Comment: +1 yes, for my case this works, but what if there would be a more complex animation, like e.g. some zigzag values? how can i repeat that? So what i am looking for is an animation which i define for let's say 20 frames and i want to add the values the next 20 frames and so on. So kind of cyclic, but additive

Comment: @Chris I'm confident all the f-Curve modifiers can be assigned to actions, as well, in the NLA editor. I would have to make a little animation to illustrate.. unless you get there first ;)

Comment: honestly...i am fighting to understand your second image...i don't get it...

Comment: @Chris What exactly are you fighting with, could you explain in detail? You add a _Cycles_ modifier to the curve and set _Before Mode_ and _After Mode_ to "Repeat with Offset". That's all there is to see in the second image.

Comment: @Chris 1 cycle is keyframed (z+4 in 25 frames). The keys' interpolation is set to 'Constant'. And then the f-Curve is given a _Cycles_ modifier with settings as shown. Improve if you like.

Comment: so are there 2 keyframes, is this right?

Comment: Right, but in the comments above you were asking if this works for more complex animations, it does: https://pasteall.org/pic/b2f3d1bf56a54f69b18cf0bbe2be83e3 as you can see here. If you don't use any restricted frame range and leave the count at 0, the "Repeat with Offset" mode basically repeats infinitely all keyframes that exist on the curve, with continuing by using the last keyframe as start for the next cycle.

Comment: @Chris Right.Frame 0,  Z=0, Frame 25, Z=4

Comment: @Chris The _Before Mode_ and _After Mode_ settings are "Repeat with Offset". You leave it at the default "Repeat Motion". But even then it would repeat, just differently. Are you sure you've selected the correct curve? Because if you did it should be shown thicker than the others. //EDIT: Just did exactly what you did, when you don't explicitly choose a curve the modifier is added to the first by default, which is X. But the movement is on Y.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: Thank you man!!! That was it!!!!

Comment: @RobinBetts: I advanced your answer...so maybe other people who make the same mistake as me won't waste their time too....Thank you!!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: I wish i could give you more than just an upvote....but i could upvote some of your old answers.... ;)

Comment: @Chris Cheers! also, if you want to copy the cycles to other curves, rather than combining  channels into an action, and modifiying the action in the NLA, check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174810/35559)

Comment: @Chris Cheers, but no need for that ;)

Answer (score 2):

ok, after i bit of thinking...driver is the solution:

i just added a driver for my x value like this:

```
floor((frame)/25) * my_value
```